# Trying to fetch a specific data but getting "Cannot read property '0' of undefined at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange"

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml, api

So basically, i'm trying to fetch a specific set of data from an API as shown in the code below.
Fetching only the football home teams' name and displaying it into a table.

Note: I can fetch the whole data from the API but when i'm trying to target only a specific object within the json data, it is displaying

```
fix.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange
```

The line i'm getting this error is at

```
var row = $('<tr><td>' + data.response[i].teams.home.name + '</td></tr>');
```

The following set of codes:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        {
            //document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = this.responseText;
            var data = this.responseText;

            for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) 
            {
               var row = $('<tr><td>' + data.response[i].teams.home.name + '</td></tr>');
               $('#myTable').append(row);


            }

        }
    }

    xhr.onerror = function()
    {
        console.log('Request Error');
    }

    xhr.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.responseText` returns a `string` and not a json object. Take a hint from the method name: reponse**Text**

You need to parse your string into JSON object

```
// Data is a string, not json
var data = this.responseText;

// Load data as a json
data = JSON.parse(data)
```

Comment: Thank you. I now understand that when fetching from an API it comes as a TEXT and you need to convert it into json  object so as to work with it. The error is gone but no data is being displayed.

Comment: i forgot to tag you @moredrowsy